# Using Expanded Widgets with ListView.separated

Tags: flutter, dart

Essentially I have a `Row` with two `Expanded` `ElevatedButtons` inside. These buttons are being dynamically built from an Array and I want to insert a `SizedBox` in-between each of these buttons.

After a bit of searching I though `ListView.separated` would be the best option however I keep running into problems. This is the Error I'm getting currently: **"Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget."** I've never had any issue using `Expanded` inside a `Column` or `Row` before so I'm not quite sure why it wouldn't work here.

*my code:*

```
final buttonTextList = [15, 30];

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 40,
      child: ListView.separated(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: widget.buttonTextList.length,
          separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(
                width: 8,
              ),
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return selectionButton(widget.buttonTextList[index], index);
          }),
    );
  }
```

```
  Widget selectionButton(value, int index) {
    return Expanded(
        child: Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setActive(index);
          widget.onPressed(context, value);
        },
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
            ),
            primary: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
        child: Text(value.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Styles.textColorLight)),
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Clearly there's something I don't understand around how `Expanded`/`Flexible` Widgets are built. My experience with Dart and Flutter is somewhat limited so any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to remove Expanded from `selectionButton` widget and what is your listview design look like @Karmar

Comment: This works however the buttons aren't full width without Expanded

Comment: remove `Expanded and Container` then enclose button with  `SizedBox(width:double.infinity,child: ElevatedButton(child: Text("FULL WIDTH"),),),` or use @Karmar

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem here you are using `Expanded` widget without making `Row` `Column` or `Flex` as parent.

Expanded widget parent must be one of above three widget.

Remove Expanded from selectionButton so your selectionButton code will be like this :-

```
  Widget selectionButton(value, int index) {
return
 Container(
  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      setActive(index);
      widget.onPressed(context, value);
    },
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
        ),
        primary: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.green : Colors.grey),
    child: Text(value.toString(),
        style: TextStyle(color: Styles.textColorLight)),
  ),
);
}
```

And add if you want to use `Expanded` add it in your parent widget where you actually have a row or column like:-

```
Column(Children:[Expanded(your widget)])
```